# Dynamic creation of a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am fetching for some values from the database, and i need to dynamicaly create a multidimensional array to look like this:

```
$found_data = 
array( 
    array('2011-11-02' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-02' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-04' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-15' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-18' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-21' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-23' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-28' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-30' => 'Mobile')
);
```

I am thinking something in the lines of:

```
$found_data = array();

while($last_30_days_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_30_days_result))
{
    $hit_date = $last_30_days_fetch['hit_date'];
    $hit_device = $last_30_days_fetch['hit_device'];    
    array_push($found_data, array($clean_date=>$hit_device));

}
```

However the above code, does not work as intended. Any ideas?

// Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$found_data = array();

while($last_30_days_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_30_days_result))
{
    $found_data[] = array($last_30_days_fetch['hit_date']=>$last_30_days_fetch['hit_device']);
}
```

why over complicate it or as Dan says put it into a single array there's no need for a multi array unless there's additional data you're not telling us about

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable $clean_date that is not defined. Check your error_reporting level it should report this (undefined variable).

PHP allows the use of the [] syntax to append elements to an array.

```
$found_data = array();

while($last_30_days_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_30_days_result))
{
    $found_data[] = array(
        $last_30_days_fetch['hit_date'] => $last_30_days_fetch['hit_device']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use:

```
$array[$hit_date] = $hit_device
```

Comment: i could not, since i needed the data packed in an array: $found_data.